# Meaning of 'more'

Tags: meaning

If someone was to say, for example:

> There should have been more food at the party

From this statement, is it possible to infer that there was no food? Or does the presence of more always indicate that the thing specified was present?

Comment: From that statement it is not possible to infer that there was no food. It is only possible to infer that someone believes that there was not enough food. Like the use of _or_ to mean both inclusive `OR` and exclusive `XOR`, comparisons can be made with a zero base or a fixed non-zero baseline. I.e, there is no necessary default presupposition of existence, though there may be one in a specific context.

Comment: I don't think  people would use "there should have been more" if there was none to start with. In the absence of food the most common way to say it would be " there should have been food at the party" . If the sentence was uttered by normal people , they would mean there was not enough food, but there was some to start with

Answer (score 4):

Generally: **No**, there was food, and **Yes**, the word *more* indicates that food was present.

However, it is possible for someone to use "more" when there is nothing (sarcasm etc.), but you would most likely already know how much there is of what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can't infer anything.

The most straight-forward meaning would be that there was food, but not enough.  But it would not be unusual for someone, in a sort of reverse hyperbole, to complain that there should have been "more food" when there was none at all.

And someone might very well say "There should have been more food" in an ironic sense, when, in their judgment, there was far too much.

Comment: Your final ironic sense - where there was already too much food - is a figure I recognise. But the earlier so-called 'reverse hyperbole' is not something I have heard - at least not in this type of context.

Comment: @WS2 - I'll admit to inventing "reverse hyperbole", in a struggle to describe the concept.

Comment: All credit to you for coining the term. But what I meant was that I had never heard anyone say - sarcastically *We could have done with more food*, when there wasn't any food. I have heard people comment dryly with something like *Did you enjoy the food?*, or *The buffet was great, wasn't it*, when there was no food on offer.

Answer (score 0):

> There should have been more food at the party.

There was already food at the party. [Food was already at the party.]

When you see a sentence begin with *There*, understand that the only time *There* is the subject is when you are referring to the word itself *there*. The subject usually comes after the verb in this type of construction, and *there* is used only to introduce and is considered an expletive.

More food should have been at the party.

Now, we easily see that in the original *more* is used as a noun and it is the subject of the sentence (not an adjective), and food is used as an appositive to describe or identify what *more* is. The verb is of course a verb phase acting as a single verb with the modal (helping verb) *should* "making the recommendation or giving advice" about having more food, Where? At the party (adverb prepositional phrase modifying the verb).

**There**. *pron*.

See Definition for Students (2)

—used to introduce a sentence in which the subject comes after the verb

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there

Sentences beginning with **There** or **Here**

See page 44.

http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/HooverCity/SpainParkHigh/Uploads/Forms/Start%20Holt%20Handbook%2010.pdf

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oddness-when-you-start-a-sentence-with-there-is

**Expletive**. *n*.

a : a syllable, word, or phrase inserted to fill a vacancy (as in a sentence or a metrical line) without adding to the sense; especially :  a word (as it in “make it clear which you prefer”) that occupies the position of the subject or object of a verb in normal English word order and anticipates a subsequent word or phrase that supplies the needed meaningful content

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expletive

**More**. *n*.

See definition of *more* as a *noun*:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more

What is an a *appositive*?

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm

The modal *should*:

http://www.englishpage.com/modals/should.html